# Totally real subfields

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, algebraic-geometry, algebraic-number-theory

Clearly, given any CM field $E$, it is known that every subfields of $E$ is either totally real or totally imaginary. Moreover, we can consider $F$ the $\bf{maximum ~totally~ real~ subfield}$ of $E$.

So, I wonder if there is $\textit{only one}$ such $F$ in $E$ or under some conditions this fact is true.

Comment: A totally complex CM-field is a quadratic extension of its maximal real subfield, which is fixed by complex conjugation.

Comment: Thank you! but could you give more detailed explanation? because for non-Galois CM field, I still get stuck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The compositum of *any* two totally real fields is totally real, so in fact for *any* number field $E$ there is a unique maximal totally real subfield $F$, which is the compositum of all the totally real subfields of $E$.

Comment: Get you. Thank you!